# How do I listen for mouse wheel presses?

Tags: java, swing, mousewheel

Is there any way to listen for mouse wheel presses (not moving the wheel, just pressing it)?

I have checked the MouseWheelListener API but there is nothing on mouse wheel presses, just wheel movings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mouse wheel button is usually mouse button 2:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

    if ((evt.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK) != 0) {
      System.out.println("middle" + (evt.getPoint()));
    }

 }
```

or even better:

```
SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent)
```

Comment: +1 for `SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(MouseEvent)`.  I have found this is inconsistent across platforms, and did not know about this method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Mouse wheel presses are reported through the `MouseListener` interface.**

Use the `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events and check the `MouseEvent.getButton()` method to return the button number pressed or released.

You can also detect clicks with the `mouseClicked` event, but I have found that the built-in criteria for mouse clicks is too narrow.  In this case, however, multiple mouse buttons could be clicked and you can use  `MouseEvent.getModifiers()` to get a bitmask of the pressed buttons.